# Extra blank records in CRM import

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to import a dataset into a custom entity in Dynamics CRM 2015 on-prem, using the import template for the entity, saved as CSV.

My dataset is quite small - only 10 rows. (Yes, I know it would probably take less time to just enter them manually).

When I import the data, CRM reads it as 3,001 records. The extra records show up totally blank. I am sure I don't have any extraneous data in other rows and columns.

Has anyone seen this, or have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: It did not return any errors. Just created a bunch of blank records.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue once. Sometimes the csv file containing some empty rows.

I have copied only the rows which containing data to a new csv file and imported it again. This approach solved my issue. 
You can try once.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to open your CSV in Notepad or some other text editor. If there are additional rows, you will see them (rows that look like ",,,,,,,".  You can delete them in the text editor and save, thereby being sure that Excel won't add the blank values back.